# Can I mark files as recently-used from the command line?

Tags: linux, files, gtk, nautilus, thunar

GTK applications mark files as recently used by adding them to the XML in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`, but I am frequently working with files from terminal-driven applications like latex, and these are not marked in the GTK list and hence not available from the "Recent" bookmark in GUI file browsers/pickers etc..

Is there a CLI command I can use to explicitly add files to the Recent list, for smoothing operations between the terminal and GUI sides of my Linux usage? Either an official way, or a fast & simple hack with the side-effect of writing to the `recently-used.xbel` file!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following Python script will add all the files given as arguments to the recently-used list, using GIO:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi, sys
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GLib

rec_mgr = Gtk.RecentManager.get_default()

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    rec_mgr.add_item(Gio.File.new_for_path(arg).get_uri())

GLib.idle_add(Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

The last two lines are necessary to start the Gtk event loop; if you don’t do that, the changed signal from the manager won’t be handled, and the files won’t be added to the recently-used list.

Comment: Good one! would you make it read from stdin? so that one can feed it through a pipe. Would be good for eg piping a `find . -type f -amin -10` into that script..

Comment: You can use `xargs` or `find`’s `-exec` — `find . -type f -amin -10 -exec add-recent {} +`.

Comment: Very true. I just thought it would be much slower though, what with re-executing the whole python executable’s bootstrap for each file

Comment: `-exec {} +` calls the script with as many files as possible in one go, not once per file, so the overhead will be very small.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I'd started going down this route myself via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836725/how-does-one-add-an-item-to-gtks-recently-used-file-list-from-python -- so I guess there's no "more official" route. I also found it useful to add an option to call `os.utime(arg, None)` to make the marked file appear at the top of the time-ordered Recent list for maximum convenience (at the cost of losing an "accurate" modification timestamp).